# Detecting collisions between all elements in two lists

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I'm making a game where there are lots of little "creatures" floating around a small area. There are also lots of little food pellets that have been created around the area. All creatures and food pellets are initializations of classes, which are in the lists `creatures` and `pellets` respectively.

There are many creatures and many pellets. I need some way to tell if *any* of the creatures are in the same location as *any* food, and if so, remove the pellet and add 1 to `creature.food`.

I know that I could use a for loop, but I am not sure how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If by lots you mean anything > 300, the simple `O(n^2)` solution will be too slow, you'll need to use a spatial data structure such as a quadtree, kdtree, or bins.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, so I will make some assumptions in an attempt of helping you out.
As you said, you have two classes: `creatures` and `pallets`. Each creature and pallet must have an attribute named `position`, which gives its 2D/3D coordinates in space. At each frame, the positions of all your objects will be updated. Then you want to know if there is some collision between some `creature` and some `pallet`. To do this compare the two list of positions with the command:

```
list(set(list_creatures_positions).intersection(list2_pallets_positions))
```

If the result is null, then you have no collision. If the result is not null, then you have a list of all positions where collisons have occurred. For all positions of this list, delete the corresponding pallet and add one in the creature.food attribute. This should be enough.